# viewing tables with pyramid seed

Tags: python, sqlite, pyramid

I'm using this seed https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_blogr
The seed uses sqlite, sqlalchemy and the pyramid frame work.
I have not modified the seed at all.

**How do I print out my tables, from a shells?**

Thank you for the help.

- I am new to pyramid, and python, but I have done introduction work on node.js and django.
- I used the sqlite3 command line with, 'sqlite3 gw.db' (gw is my app named), but i think this started a new db instance.
- I am working on an Ubuntu 14.04 server with a mean stack installed.

Comment: SO is not the right place for this type of question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist alright, I just became a member of dba.stackexchange, after my 40 minute hold has elapsed I will post my question there as well. Is there another community you would like to suggest?

Comment: I think that will be fine. You may want to remove "I have tried a few blogs and searches, including sqlite3, but I have not had any success with those, and I believe there is a much simpler way." unless you plan to substantiate that with some examples of the things you tried.

Answer (score 1):

To print sqlite tables via shell, use the [`sqlite3` command-line utility](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html). It's not clear whether you want to print a list of tables, the database schema, or in what output format, but all of that is covered in the documentation.